# Adding JS function as third parameter in do_action

Tags: plugin-development

I have this JS function named as "myjsfunction()".

```
function myjsfunction() {

jQuery('#html_admin_show').hide();
jQuery('#html_admin_edit').show();

}
```

One limitation is that I cannot edit the original JS function like to put some PHP tags, etc.

How is it possible to call this JS function inside a Wordpress do_action hook?

I'm preferring to add it as third parameter because I'm already using the second parameter, so something like:

```
do_action('myhelp', 'mysecondfunction', 'myjsfunction');
```

But it is not showing the element #html_admin_edit when the page runs. Any ideas how to call this function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your callback must be PHP:

```
function myjsfunction_callback() {
?>
<script>myjsfunction();</script>
<?php
}
```

Second, you can add multiple callbacks to one action:

```
add_action( 'myhelp', 'myjsfunction_callback' );
add_action( 'myhelp', 'mysecondfunction' );
```

Now, you can call `do_action()` without parameter …

```
do_action( 'myhelp' );
```

… and both callbacks will be executed.

---

I reply to your comment: You can use just *one* callback:

```
do_action( 'myhelp', 'mysecondfunction', 'myjsfunction_callback' );
```

You have to use a rather abstract callback then, and accept more parameters:

```
add_action( 'myhelp', 'multicall', 10, 99 );

function multicall()
{
    $functions = func_get_args();

    foreach ( $functions as $function )
    {
        if ( function_exists( $function ) )
            $function();
    }
}
```

Now you can pass up to 99 function names, and all of them will be executed for that action.

Comment: Thanks, this one will work but I cannot edit the JS function because it belongs to a third party plugin. Any ideas how to make the callback in PHP?

Comment: @CodexMeridian See my update. :)

Comment: One problem I noticed is that I only want to have one line of do_action with the myjsfunction_callback as the third parameter, In your example, you have a do_action without a parameter. can you give me an example of a do_action above using myjsfunction_callback as the third parameter? Thanks.

Comment: @CodexMeridian See my update.